# Using sbt-native-packager to instrument prometheus exporter via JavaServerAppPackaging

Tags: scala, sbt-native-packager, prometheus-java

I am trying to instrument a java app with [prometheus exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter) using `sbt-native-packager`:

This is what I have:

***plugin.sbt***

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.5.1")
```

***build.sbt***

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.docker.DockerChmodType
dockerChmodType := DockerChmodType.UserGroupWriteExecute
enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging, AshScriptPlugin, DockerPlugin)
settings(moduleName := "my-test")
settings(mainClass in Compile := Some("org.name.demo.stream.MyTestClass"))
dockerBaseImage := "openjdk:8-jre-alpine"
daemonUser in Docker    := "test"
```

As per the prometheus exporter docs, I would like to instrument the exporter as an java agent:

```
java -javaagent:./jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.12.0.jar=8080:config.yaml -jar my-test_2.12-0.1.jar
```

Is it possible for me to do this instrumentation via `sbt-native-packager`? Appreciate inputs.

Comment: Hi there. There is a section for customization here: https://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/archetypes/java_app/customize.html#via-build-sbt Does this help?

Comment: I will try this out and update.. Appreciate it..

Answer (score 1):

Use https://github.com/sbt/sbt-javaagent
In **plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.sbt" % "sbt-javaagent" % "0.1.6")
```

then in **build.sbt**

```
val MyAppSettings = Seq(
  name := "My",
  dockerBaseImage := "adoptopenjdk:11-jre-hotspot",
  mainClass := Some("com.MyClass"),
  packageName in Docker := "mycontainer",
  libraryDependencies ++= myDependencies,
  javaAgents += JavaAgent("io.prometheus.jmx" % "jmx_prometheus_javaagent" % "0.16.1", arguments = "33002:/opt/docker/jmx-exporter.yaml"),
  mappings in Universal ++= Seq(
    file("jmx-exporter.yaml") -> "jmx-exporter.yaml"
  )
)

lazy val myProject = (project in file("my-project"))
  .settings(MyAppSettings)
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, JavaAgent)
```